Can someone explain Serum?
I'm trying to understand project Serum on Solana.
I know that it created an onchain orderbook which uses liquidity pools but here's what I'm having a hard time understand:
As far as I know, liquidity pools manage the prices of the assets in the pool by a constant product formula whereas an orderbook allows setting limit orders, trailing stops,  etc.
So how does one create an orderbook depending on liquidity pools?
Unrelated to Solana but I think the Bullish exchange also is doing something similar: https://bullish.com/amm/
